# Many to many relationship with a way to know active entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship as follows:

> A **Requests** could be received by one or more **Employees**
>
> An **Employee** could receive one or more **Requests**

Each request will be received by multiple employees but actually there will be only one employee working on it and when he finishes the other employee will start working on it

I will make a table that has the ID of each entity, but the question is:

**I need to know who is the current active employee**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this sounds like you deal with two separate relationships that need separate representations in your data model

- a) Employee (has recieved) Request (n:m)
- b) Employee (works on) Request (1:n)

(where (b) has the additional constraint that it needs to be a subset of (a))